# How to take param values from Task Queue url.?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
queue.add(("/worker").param("key", "ABC"));
```

how to take key value .? using below code or any other approach.

```
request.getParameter("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. The `/worker` endpoint is configured in your `web.xml` as a Servlet. The `request` object will be passed to your Servlet method and you can use the standard methods like the one you have specified i.e. `getParameter(...)`